# Variable grayed out in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Seems like my initial problem is solved but the function is only returning the sum of the 1st sub-array. I can't figure out why the first for-loop outside of the function is returning the sum of all the sub arrays but the function itself is only returning the sum of the first sub array. I was thinking it would loop down each sub array again and add all the numbers together:

```
function loop(){
    for(let i =0; i < numSquare.length; i++){
        let loop1 = numSquare[i];
        let sum = 0;
        console.log(loop1)
        for(let k=0; k< loop1.length; k++){
            sum += loop1[k]
        }  
        return  (`${sum}`);
    }

}
```

While practicing looping through a multi-array, I created a function to store the looped values below but variable "loop2" is grayed out in visual studio code saying it is not defined even though I have already defined to be equal to numSquare[i]? I am trying to create a function, as the first part works without it being in a function.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
const numSquare = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
];

for (let i = 0; i < numSquare.length; i++) {
    let loop1 = numSquare[i]
    let sum = 0;
    console.log(loop1)
    for (let k = 0; k < loop1.length; k++) {
        sum += loop1[k]
    }
    console.log(`${loop1} summs up to be ${sum}`)
}

//This one does not work because it is telling me loop2 is NOT defined but clearly is defined?

function loop(){
    for(let i = 0 ; i< numSquare.length; i++){
        let loop2 = numSquare[i]
        let sum2 = 0;
        for(let k=0; k< loop2.length; k++){
            sum2+= loop2[k]
        }
    }
    return console.log(`${loop2} sums up to be ${sum2}`)
}
```

Comment: Look at the scope in which the variable is defined and where it is used

Comment: You're accessing it in console, where you have defined it in for loop

Comment: “let” scope is not global scope.

Comment: So, in VS Code the variable only greyed out and there was no error message displayed in the terminal? You might want to install ESLint to solve these issues.

Comment: @palash DeepScan is great too, I use it alongside ESLint in VS Code and have them set to not have any redundancies between them, so I get the best of both without having any errors reported twice. DeepScan does not require that you install any dependencies, just install the extension from VS Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're defining variable with let so it is block scoped, and you're trying to access in console which is not the same scope

```
function loop(){
    for(let i = 0 ; i< numSquare.length; i++){
    |    let loop2 = numSquare[i]    <--- loop2
    |    let sum2 = 0;
    |    for(let k=0; k< loop2.length; k++){
    |        sum2+= loop2[k]
    |    }
    }
    // out of block so loop2 is not accessable
    return console.log(`${loop2} sums up to be ${sum2}`)
}
```